# String extraction/manipulation in Java

Tags: java, string

```
String url = "http://someurl/search.do?/remainingurl"
```

I would like to scrape the above string from the first character upto search.do?

Meaning, the resulting String would look like so:

```
String scrapedUrl = "http://someurl/search.do?"
```

Is there a String operation in Java to achieve the above action ?

Thanks,
Sony

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
String scrapedUrl = url.replaceAll("(.*?search\\.do\\?).*", "$1");
```

Of course you can use `indexOf` solutions and all of that, but your requirement was to exactly ''match'' everything up until the first `search.do?`. That kind of operation is best done using a regular expression.

Comment: The problem with indexOf is that it will give you the reference to either the start or the end of the string you are looking for.  If it is the end, you are fine.  If it is the start, you have to add on the characters in the search string.  Regular expression here is a neat way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (untested):

```
int index = url.indexOf("?");
if (index >= 0)
    url= url.substring(0, index);
```

It looks for the first occurance of the '?' character and if found chops off the characters that follow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of indexOf() and subString() to chop up the String.  Check out the methods of String in the API:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use this : [`subString(start, end)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) and [`indexOf(string)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

```
final String splitter = "search.do?";
String[] strings = url.split("search\\.do\\?");
String scrapedUrl = strings[0] + splitter;
```

Read [more](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

```
    String url = "http://someurl/search.do?/remainingurl";
   String scrapedUrl =url.substring(0,url.lastIndexOf("?")+1);
   System.out.println(scrapedUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

```
int index = url.indexOf("?");
String newURL = url.subString(0,index);
```

Comment: You'll need to test that `indexOf()` actually found something, else you'll get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` from `substring()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [substring](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) and [indexOf](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29)

```
String scrapedUrl = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('?');
```